# DNS records: Save emails in two different mail servers depending of the subdomain

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, cloudflare

I'm using Namecheap Web hosting with cpanel, I want the emails sent to `domain.tld` to be saved into the Namecheap's Private Email (non cpanel), and the emails sent to `sub.domaim.tld` saved to the cpanel hosting.

I'm trying to use Cloudflare as well, but I don't understand why cpanel and Cloudflare DNS records are different.

Comment: Its difficult to answer this without more knowledge. Can you provide the domain name so we can look at what's going in? To set up email for a subdomain to go somewhere simply set up an MX record for subdomain pointing to the appropriate mail server.  Its quite possible when you started using cloudflare you set the name server records for the zone to cloudflares, in which case the cpanel ones will be being ignored.

Comment: When I added the subdomain to cpanel it didn't add a MX record for it, however it recives email anyway... but when I change the MX records to private email's and add a MX record for the subdomain it does not get email

Comment: If you don't have an MX record mail will try and fall back to an A record.